# God issuing prophecy in the name of idols

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, avodah-zarah, nevua-prophecy

I once read somewhere in the Gemara that a Rabbi asked how come idolaters claim that, as they walked by an idol, the god made a prediction (or gave advice) that came true. The answer was that God issues prophecies in the guise of idols to lead idolaters to their downfall.

Does anyone know what page this is on?

Comment: there's something similar about Achav who God led astray by the ruach (spirit) of the man he murdered.